# How to change multiple elements in useState array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have an issue with my Hangman app im creating.I'm stuck at the stage when im trying to program the letters reveal while clicking on them.

Hangman.js

```
import al from '../alphabet'
import {HangmanContext} from '../context/HangmanContext'

const Hangman = (props) =>{
    const {password,displayGame,displayForm} = useContext(HangmanContext)

    const [subject,setSubject] = password
    const [gameDisplay,setGameDisplay] = displayGame
    const [createSubjectDisplay,setCreateSubjectDisplay] = displayForm
    
    let passwordArr = Array.from(subject)
    
    
    const [hiddenPassword,changeHiddenPassword] = useState([''])

        useEffect(() => {
            let passwordArr = Array.from(subject)
            console.log(passwordArr)
            changeHiddenPassword(passwordArr.map(item => '_'))
        },[subject]);
    
    

    

    const chooseLetter = (e) => {
        let letter = e.target.innerHTML
        passwordArr.forEach((s,i) => {
            if (s == letter){
                  console.log(hiddenPassword)
                  changeHiddenPassword(hiddenPassword.map((item,j) => {
                      if(j == i){
                          item = subject[i]
                      }
                      return item
                  }))
                }
                console.log(hiddenPassword)
        })
    }
    

    const letters = al.map((letter) =>
        <span onClick={chooseLetter}>{letter}</span>
    )

    
    

    return(
        <div style={{display:gameDisplay}}>
            <div className='password'>
                {
                passwordArr.map((item,i) => <span>{hiddenPassword[i]}</span>)
                }
            </div>
            <div className='wrapper'>
                <div className='pass_input'>Enter password:<input type='text' maxLength='30'/></div>
                <div className='alphabet'> {letters} </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Hangman
```

In my chooseLetter function im trying to change hiddenPassword state that contains initially as many "_" as is the password length(which i have fixed in another state ) to the point where it has revealed clicked letter.It works fine when the password contain letters that doesn't repeat. When letters in the password are repeating, revealing them only works for the last of them and i want them to reveal all.

Comment: This is just a guess, but the issue might be due to the asynchronous nature of changeHiddenPassword.  Try passing in a function to changeHiddenPassword to ensure that you always have the latest value of Hidden Password.

Comment: @ashishTuteja could you say something more about your idea? I'm new to React Hooks and i dont exacty know what you mean by "passing in a function to changeHiddenPassword to ensure that I always have the latest value of Hidden Password". I have tried ```changeHiddenPassword((prevState,j) => if(i==j) {hiddenPassword[i] = subject[i] })```

Comment: I was thinking something like this:
`changeHiddenPassword(p => p.map((item,j) => j === i ? subject[i] : item));`

Comment: I was thinking that since changeHiddenPass is async, you can't be sure that the value of HiddenPassword has changed before the nextiteration of the for loop. Just because you called changeHiddenPass in the firstiteration doesn't mean you'll get the updated value of HiddenPassword in the second or third iterations.  You might end up where it's the last iteration of the for loop but HiddenP. isn't updated.  But since  map only impacts one position we see a change in that position.  This solution does seem to work in [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-mccarthy-6sxrf?file=/src/index.js).

Comment: Yes that was right solution. I need to look a little bit diffrently at async functions.Thank you very much